# insert into value in select statement mutliple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I try to insert into table with 1 column is (select from table).

I should copy all the id to table1 with 1 column is (select from table )

This not working:

```
insert into table1 (id,resoucrce,rate)  values ((select id from table2),0,0)
```

I want to do something like that insert all the id from table to another table with default values.

Answer (score 4):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
 insert into table1 (id, resource, rate) 
    select id, 0, 0
    from table2;
```

Comment: @Asad Can you ACCEPT THE ANSWER if it is working?  you have questions on SO and have accepted NO answers

Answer (score 2):

For copy the content of one table to another table within the same database use this :-

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (`col1`,`col2`) SELECT `col1`,`col2` FROM SOURCE_TABLE;
```

or your query like that :-

```
Insert into table1 (id, resource, rate) select id, 0, 0 from table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should focus **"values"** keyword;

```
values ((select id from table2),0,0)
```

When you use **values(, , ,)** you have to specify **value columns.** But you're trying to pass both **resultset** and **single values** together. That's why you get an error. You should only pass single values...

If its clear for you; you can easily find the correct sql syntax.